# Is it a good idea to train a Neural Network on continiously randomly generated training data?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Hello everyone I'm building a license plate detection model in Tensorflow. I built a function that chooses a license plate at random from a collection of ~5000 plates and puts it in a random place in on a random background and saves the coordinates. At first I thought to generate about 40K images this way and train the network on with the generated data. But wouldn't it be a good idea to just continiously keep generating new data to feed to the network and basically eliminate any chance of it getting overfitted?

Comment: This question is a bit broad for StackOverflow (we only deal with specific programming questions here) but you might want to try https://datascience.stackexchange.com since they have more experience with the actual data science side of things

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent way to train it on how to spot the discontinuities around a superimposed yellow / white / blue rectangle, but maybe not such a great way of teaching it to spot a real license plate. If you've got a good way of procedurally generating images then great! but be warned.

It might spot the wrong pattern.